# How to let user pick date AND time in the form?

Tags: python, django, datetime, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a sort of To Do List. Majority of it is done. I can get user to enter the task, along with its detail and pick the starting and ending date.

However, since I am rendering the fields in a form, I want the user to easily and conveniently enter the date and time. For that I have added a datepicker type widget. The datetime stored in database is still in ISO format.

Now, the issue is that user can pick or enter the date perfectly fine. But it *does not allow the user to enter the time.* Once the date has been picked, the user can't enter the time.

The code goes as under:

```py
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskModel
        exclude = ["completed"]
        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"} ),
            'detail': Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'start_time': DateInput(format = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'], attrs={"type":"date", 'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input', 'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'}),
            'end_time': DateInput(format = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'], attrs={"type": "date", 'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input'})  
        }
```

And the **Model.py** file is:

```py
class TaskModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(blank = True, null=True)
```

The rest of the code is just simple and conventional Django based views and templates (let me know if you need that too).

I am also attaching an image of a form to let you see how it looks like.
[image: Form depicting datetime picker widget]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `AdminSplitDateTime` from django admin

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskModel
        exclude = ["completed"]
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'detail': forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'start_time': widgets.AdminSplitDateTime(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'end_time': widgets.AdminSplitDateTime(attrs={"class": "form-control"})  
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it didn't work for me.

Actually, I came across this incredible github repo that helps me complete my exact task with very small customizations. 
https://github.com/monim67/django-flatpickr

I was able to achieve exactly what I want using this repo.